# Robustness for posix spin locks

Tags: pthreads, posix, spinlock

I'm writing a library that needs a fast ipc lock, around a small critical section. I want to ensure that crashes in unrelated code, during the critical section, will still release the ipc lock.

In this example, `main` creates a shared memory object and memory maps it. Initializes the memory as a `pthread_spinlock_t` with `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`, allowing multiple processes to use the same lock.

```
void proc1_main() {
  auto shm_obj = ...

  pthread_spin_lock((pthread_spinlock_t*)shm_obj.ptr);
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
  pthread_spin_unlock((pthread_spinlock_t*)obj.ptr);
}

void proc2_main() {
  auto shm_obj = ...

  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

  cout << "waiting for spin lock...\n";
  pthread_spin_lock((pthread_spinlock_t*)shm_obj.ptr);
  cout << "got spin lock\n";
  pthread_spin_unlock((pthread_spinlock_t*)shm_obj.ptr);
}

int main() {
  auto shm_obj = ...
  pthread_spin_init((pthread_spinlock_t*)shm_obj.ptr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  shm_obj.close();

  if (::fork()) {
    proc1_main();
  } else {
    proc2_main();
  }
}
```

The sleeps ensure that process ordering is (more-or-less) guaranteed.

- `proc1` grabs the spin lock.
- `proc2` prints "waiting for spin lock...".
- `proc2` starts waiting on the spin lock.
- `proc1` releases the spin lock.
- `proc2` acquires the spin lock.
- `proc2` prints "got spin lock".
- `proc2` releases the spin lock.

This is all good and expected behavior for a lock.

I'm concerned what happens if a process crashes and doesn't release the lock.

```
void proc1_main() {
  auto shm_obj = ...

  pthread_spin_lock((pthread_spinlock_t*)shm_obj.ptr);
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
  // pthread_spin_unlock((pthread_spinlock_t*)obj.ptr);
}
```

With this modification, `proc1` completes without releasing the spin lock. `proc2` hangs forever.

If I was using a pthread_mutex_t, I could add the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` flag and continue on. I don't need to worry about consistency.

Is there any robustness for spin locks?

Comment: What kind of resource does the spin lock protect? What precisely do you want to happen if a process crashes while holding the spin lock? (For example, do you want the next thread to try to acquire the lock to just get it without being notified that whatever the lock protects may have been left in an inconsistent state?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I just want the crashing program to release the lock.
Far more detail: the lock protects a double-buffered struct in shared-memory. The critical section sets a few values in the writable buffer, then atomically swaps the buffers. The shared-memory is still always in a consistent state, even if the program crashes half way through, since the active buffer is always the result of the atomic swap.

Comment: That's a sufficiently unusual requirement that you'll probably need to make your own implementation.

Comment: Is the assumption with `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` that none of the processes will crash? Is there really no way to recover?

Comment: The assumption is that if a process crashes while holding the lock, it may leave shared data in an inconsistent state and thus any recovery process will involve truly extraordinary measures such as terminating all processes that access the shared resource. You may have to use something like a file lock instead.

Comment: I'm currently using pthread_mutex_t with the PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST flag. In benchmarks, spin lock is an order of magnitude faster than mutex, which is ~2 orders of magnitude faster than file locks.

Comment: I suspect your benchmarks are too synthentic and don't reflect any realistic scenario. Testing synchronization primitives in tight loops, for example, will give you no clue how they will behave in scenarios that are not tight loops. And, most importantly, frequently fail to take into account the effect that the operation has on other, unrelated tasks the system is doing. For example, one implementation may seem faster, but it may saturate inter-core resources that adversely affect other cores running entirely different code. I'd guess there's a 90% chance you're optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: A pthread mutex is basically instantaneous when it succeeds (in linux at least). I assume the major difference with the spinlock is that it *spins* instead of blocking when it does *not* immediately succeed and so is able to "resume" execution faster once it obtains the lock. It stands to reason that you may be able to get the same effect by using `pthread_mutex_trylock` in a loop of your own (that function does not block if it cannot take the lock). The advantage being that you could then use the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` facility and would be able to recover when one of your processes crashed.

Comment: "... instantaneous when it succeeds *immediately* ..." That is, when uncontended